# Error in adding foreign key from an existing table to a existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I ve two tables , one is

```
ticket_details(ticket_id,cab_name,cab_no,ticket_number)
```

Here ticket_id is my primary key

second one is

```
user_detail(user_id,name,email,password,gender,location)
```

Here user_id is my primary key,
I want to add the user_id as a foreign key in my ticket_details table.

I tried some codes, but it's showing me errors. Any help ?? thank u in advance.

Comment: ALTER IGNORE TABLE ticket_details
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id)
REFERENCES user_detail(user_id)

Comment: You used the wrong codes.

Comment: hey but i want to add my foreign key in my ticket_details tables, so u cant give it as the reference

Answer (score 0):

You may try in order (if user_id is int):

1. `ALTER TABLE ticket_details ADD user_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;`
2. Populate your new user_id column with valid values.
3. `ALTER TABLE ticket_details ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_detail(user_id);`

Comment: They'd need to actually give `user_id` valid values in `ticket_details` before they can add the foreign key constraint.

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eciticket_db`.`#sql-87c_10d`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_detail` (`user_id`))

i m getting this error

Comment: Look at the previous comment. You need to populate your new user_id column with valid values before adding the foreign key constraint. I will edit my answer.

Comment: now can u tell me to how to delete a foreign key constraint ??

Comment: `ALTER TABLE your_table DROP FOREIGN KEY your_foreign_key;`